# What percentage of total Ether was held by TheDAO?

Tags: ether

Recent news of someone stealing from TheDAO suggest that it had a lot of Ether. How much of the total amount of Ether did it control?

Answer (score 3):

The dao has close to 8 million eth.

[DAO supply](https://etherscan.io/address/0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413)

Of the currently 81 million eth.

[Eth Supply](https://etherscan.io/stats/supply)

Comment: How much did it had before getting attacked?

Comment: It's my understanding that the attack has changed the owner of DAO tokens, but no ether has been drained from the DAO since it's inception. That would require a split and drain which takes at least 30 days.  http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3748/how-to-withdraw-ether-from-the-dao

Comment: @tranqy: Don't think so, the number is going down. My understanding is they stole the ether but not the tokens.

Comment: Based on this post looks like the Dao originally had closer to 11 million.  https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4p7ck0/dao_hack_timeline/