# How was the recursive call vulnerability attack conducted via proposal #59 when there were no Yes votes?

Tags: security, the-dao, attacks

From [Which split proposal was used to mount the recursive call vulnerability attack on The DAO?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6223/which-split-proposal-was-used-to-mount-the-recursive-call-vulnerability-attack-o), proposal #59 is very likely the vector uses by the attacker to hack 3,641,694.241898506 Ether ($59,578,117.80) (from [Is there any way to determine how long it took for the DAO attacker to deploy the attack?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6174/is-there-any-way-to-determine-how-long-it-took-for-the-dao-attacker-to-deploy-th)).

From my understanding only individuals voting Yes on the split proposals to be able to withdraw ETH from The DAO (see [How to withdraw Ether from The DAO?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3748/how-to-withdraw-ether-from-the-dao/5705#5705)).

Also from [Deconstructing theDAO Attack: A Brief Code Tour](http://vessenes.com/deconstructing-thedao-attack-a-brief-code-tour/):

> The mechanism for doing so is to create a split proposal. Split proposals take 7 days to 'mature' and get participants in. **Any participants voting "yes" in the split will be given the right to call splitDAO.**
>
> splitDAO will create the DAO child contract if it doesn't exist, send the ether controlled by the splitters into the childDAO, pay out any accrued 'reward' pro-rata to the splitters, and return. At least, that's the plan.

And from [DAO.report](https://dao.report/) you can see that no one voted Yes to proposal #59:

[image]

[image]

You can see the same information for proposal #59 in [Which split proposal was used to mount the recursive call vulnerability attack on The DAO?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6223/which-split-proposal-was-used-to-mount-the-recursive-call-vulnerability-attack-o).

From the source code for `splitDAO(...)` (from [EtherScan.io - The DAO](http://etherscan.io/address/0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413#code)) there is a restriction `!p.votedYes[msg.sender]` that throws an error if the `splitDAO(...)` function call was called by a caller who has not voted Yes:

```
    function splitDAO(
        uint _proposalID,
        address _newCurator
    ) noEther onlyTokenholders returns (bool _success) {
 
        Proposal p = proposals[_proposalID];
 
        // Sanity check
 
        if (now < p.votingDeadline  // has the voting deadline arrived?
            //The request for a split expires XX days after the voting deadline
            || now > p.votingDeadline + splitExecutionPeriod
            // Does the new Curator address match?
            || p.recipient != _newCurator
            // Is it a new curator proposal?
            || !p.newCurator
            // Have you voted for this split?
            || !p.votedYes[msg.sender]
            // Did you already vote on another proposal?
            || (blocked[msg.sender] != _proposalID && blocked[msg.sender] != 0) )  {
 
            throw;
        }
```

So, how was the attacker able to drain the ETH from The DAO when they did not vote Yes on proposal #59?

Was there another vector that was employed by the attacker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User [DTO](https://forum.daohub.org/users/DTO) in a DAOhub.org post [How was the recursive call vulnerability attack conducted via proposal #59 when there were no Yes votes?](https://forum.daohub.org/t/how-was-the-recursive-call-vulnerability-attack-conducted-via-proposal-59-when-there-were-no-yes-votes/5293/2) pointed out:

> There were two yes votes, just very low on tokens and are rounded down to zero:
>
> ```
> 0xc0ee9db1a9e07ca63e4ff0d5fb6f86bf68d47b89
> 0xf835a0247b0063c04ef22006ebe57c5f11977cc4
> ```

But both accounts have 0 The DAO tokens - the tokens may have been transferred away:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ theDAOVoter --listaccounts --account=0xc0ee9db1a9e07ca63e4ff0d5fb6f86bf68d47b89
  # Account                                                            ETH                        DAO The DAO transfer blocked by OPEN proposal?
--- ------------------------------------------ --------------------------- -------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------
  0 0xc0ee9db1a9e07ca63e4ff0d5fb6f86bf68d47b89        0.000000645417097014         0.0000000000000000 
--- ------------------------------------------ --------------------------- -------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------
  1 Total                                             0.000000645417097014         0.0000000000000000
user@Kumquat:~$ theDAOVoter --listaccounts --account=0xf835a0247b0063c04ef22006ebe57c5f11977cc4
  # Account                                                            ETH                        DAO The DAO transfer blocked by OPEN proposal?
--- ------------------------------------------ --------------------------- -------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------
  0 0xf835a0247b0063c04ef22006ebe57c5f11977cc4        0.000000645417097014         0.0000000000000000 
--- ------------------------------------------ --------------------------- -------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------
  1 Total                                             0.000000645417097014         0.0000000000000000
```

From the [0xc0ee9db1a9e07ca63e4ff0d5fb6f86bf68d47b89 transaction listing](http://etherscan.io/token/TheDAO?a=0xc0ee9db1a9e07ca63e4ff0d5fb6f86bf68d47b89#txns), there were many transfers of 25,805.6141471 DAOs up until 1 day 2 hrs ago (6/17/2016 12:27:23 PM), including a transfers from 0xf835a0247b0063c04ef22006ebe57c5f11977cc4. The last transfer was to [0xca04d260356d19f0d7255041542c9cbc866f2cb3](http://etherscan.io/address/0xca04d260356d19f0d7255041542c9cbc866f2cb3).

And from [0xc0ee9db1a9e07ca63e4ff0d5fb6f86bf68d47b89](http://etherscan.io/token/TheDAO?a=0xc0ee9db1a9e07ca63e4ff0d5fb6f86bf68d47b89#votes) and [0xf835a0247b0063c04ef22006ebe57c5f11977cc4](http://etherscan.io/token/TheDAO?a=0xf835a0247b0063c04ef22006ebe57c5f11977cc4#votes), you can see both accounts vote on both proposals #59 and #64.

Here's some data on proposal #64:

```
=======================================================================
Proposal 64. OPEN until Thu Jun 16 16:02:14 2016 [-2d 05h 59m 39s]
Votes       YEA 3069670 (99.99%) nay 250 (0.01%) Quorum 0.27% of 20%
Creator     0x547389052a8dc86365c46641b5184956ec22749d
Recipient   0x547389052a8dc86365c46641b5184956ec22749d
Deposit     0 ETH
Amount      0 ETH
New curator Y
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
0x54738 Split
=======================================================================
```

So proposal #64 could be another attack vector? (But I don't know what has stopped the attack via proposal #59).

Comment: Does it really make sense to create all the community wiki posts?

Comment: Don't know. Please advice.

Comment: I'm unsure myself, but I don't see people contributing to wiki posts very often. And I think it might be better to use the edit-queue or create a separate answer. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/226837) and [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) are some resources.